# Dynamic 2 array in C

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, 2d

I am learning C and I am trying to have a virtual grid in it, where the user can put new grid elements to "activate" into the console. So for example if I am starting with nothing and the user adds (40,50), then the size is at least 40x50 with element (40,50) initialised. If (20,30) follows, it just activates the element at 20,30. But if the user then enters (500,300), it will allocate some more memory and increases the size of the array. I would like to access them easily. I would like to work (I might have to anyway), because they are new for me.
My code (at the moment) is the following:

```
int width = 4, height = 5;
bool **arr = (bool **) malloc(height * sizeof(bool *));
for (int x = 0; x < height; x++) {
    arr[x] = (bool *) malloc(width * sizeof(bool));
}

for (int x = 0; x < height; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < width; y++) {
        *(*(arr + x) + y) = false;
    }
}

*(*(arr + 3) + 2) = true;

// user puts a value bigger than (4,5) inside
int newX=10, newY = 10;

//allocate more memory
```

So I am using a 2D pointer with booleans and I do "malloc" the height first and afterwards make an array of them for the width.

In the last line is just an example of entering the first element at (2,3). The scan method for the user doesn't matter here.

So is there a way of increasing the size of my array afterwards or do I need a totally different concept for it?

=====
The current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
    int width = 4, height = 5;
    bool **arr = (bool **) malloc(height * sizeof(bool *));

    for (int x = 0; x < height; x++) {
        arr[x] = (bool *) malloc(width * sizeof(bool));
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < height; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < width; y++) {
            *(*(arr + x) + y) = false;
        }
    }

    *(*(arr + 3) + 2) = true;

    int newWidth = 10, newHeight = 10;
    bool **narr = realloc(arr, newHeight * sizeof(bool*));
    if(narr) {
        arr = narr;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < newHeight; i++){
            bool* p = realloc(arr[i] , newWidth * sizeof(bool));
            if( !p ){
                perror("realloc");
            }
            arr[i] = p;
        }
        // here resize the number of elements if needed
    }
    else {
        perror("realloc failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but for any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`. That means e.g. `*(arr + 3)` is equal to `arr[3]`, and furthermore that `*(*(arr + 3) + 2)` is equal to `arr[3][2]`.

Comment: If the array is sparse then there are other data structures that you could use.

Comment: Nitpicking: `bool** arr` defines `arr` to be a pointer to pointer to `bool`. So in fact type wise you do *not* define a 2D array, but one **1**D array with `height` pointer elements plus `height` **1**D arrays with `width` boolean elements.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. You are right about the 1D array, I was actually knowing about it, but explained it wrong. That was the reason why is used *(*(arr + x) + y) instead of arr[y][x], because that helped me understanding calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a mathod called [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc). And you can use that. You can resize the jagged array completely.

```
bool **narr = realloc(arr , newsize * sizeof(bool*));
if( narr ) {
  arr = narr;
  for(size_t i = 0; i < newsize; i++){
     bool* p = realloc(arr[i] , newsize1 * sizeof(bool));
     if( !p ){
        perror("realloc");
     }
     arr[i] = p;
  }
  // here resize the number of elements if needed
}
else {
    perror("realloc failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Also simplify things write `a[1][2]` instead of `*(*(a+1)+2)`. The check is needed as `realloc` may fail - in that case instead of letting your code go awry, take appropriate step as needed.

Also note that you need to set all the newly allocated `bool*` to `NULL`. So do this:-

```
    for(size_t i = 0; i < newHeight; i++){
        if( i >= height)
           arr[i] = NULL;
        bool* p = realloc(arr[i] , newWidth * sizeof(bool));
        if( !p ){
            perror("realloc");
        }
        arr[i] = p;
    }
```

This is needed because `realloc` expects address of memory previously allocated with `*alloc` functions or `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I do understand what you are doing, but please tell me about the line "realloc(arr[i] , newsize1 * sizeof(bool));" Why do I need arr[i] in it? With that, I am getting malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff5edd5c33: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated. With just arr, I get a fully initialised array, but with wrong elements (see my comment to @Ran Elgiser, which is the same solution then (although with a good check before.)

Comment: By the way, `perror` *does not affect the program flow in any way*, so it alone isn't sufficient here. You'd probably want to exit, abort, return NULL but *not* continue.

Comment: @FranzFerdinand.: I dont get your point... you are reallocating to `arr[i]` that's why you need it.

Comment: @user9816091 I do understand about arr[i] now, thank you very much. But I am getting the message "error for object 0x7fff5edd5c33: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated" when using it like that. I might have got a stupid mistake in my way of doing it. I've just updated the current code in the topic. Thanks for your idea so far!

Comment: @FranzFerdinand.: I guess you didn't allocate it correctly. Always check the return value of `malloc/realloc`...also remember - to apply `realloc` you need to have `arr[i]` allocated using `malloc/realloc`.

Comment: It must be something with the line bool* p = realloc(arr[i] , newWidth * sizeof(bool));. But I actually don't know whats wrong with it, because it's actually the same we are doing two lines before, just in the other "dimension" of our "2D array" (one dimensional pointer).

Comment: @FranzFerdinand.: Debugging can help here...unless I see your full code it's impossible for me to tell.

Comment: Hey, I have updated my current **full** code in the main thread above. It actually was there before, just without int main { } before and after. That is currently the only thing I am having inside the file after getting rid of things not relating to the topic. At the moment I trying to debug it by editing various lines to see the changes.

Comment: @FranzFerdinand.: Edited. Check it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I do understand whats happening here ... And it's working. Please answer me one last question: Is reallocating to extend the 2D array size efficient for very large sizes? I do not plan to work with it in a serious program, I am just experimenting, but something makes me thinking, my idea for that "problem" is still inefficient. But the problem is solved now, thank you!

Comment: @FranzFerdinand.: It depends...you should allocate large size and then later based on the usage u can reallocate it to a smaller size. But again this can be best answered given the specific situation.

Answer (score -2):

You can use *realloc* to increase the size of the array

in your situation you'd do

```
arr = (bool **)realloc(arr, sizeof(bool*) * new_height)
for(int i = 0; i < new_height; i++){
    arr[i] = (bool *)realloc(arr, sizeof(bool) * new_width);
}
```

Note that you have to check whether the array needs to even get bigger, realloc can also "shrink" your array so tread carefully.

Initializing the newly created memory to false:

```
for(int i = old_height; i < new_height; i++){
    for(int j = old_width; j < new_width; j++){
        arr[i][j] = false;
    }
}
arr[new_height - 1][new_width - 1] = true;
```

Comment: In C those casts are useless.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. This solution is actually increasing the size, that is correct, but it's not keeping the elements of the old array. So in my example, I had false (0) everywhere except (2,3). Afterwards, I am having first column all with 0, second with 1, third with 0 and so on. So it's increasing the size but destroying old data.

Comment: 1. incorrect use of `realloc`, 2. unnecessary casts, 3 wrong pointer given to `realloc` as the argument..

Comment: @FranzFerdinand: `realloc()` is *guaranteed* to  *not* change the content. If you do observer this something le is going wrong.

Comment: Realloc does in fact keep the elements of the old array, it's just that the newly allocated space is not yet initialized, you'd need to initialize the new memory yourself, I'll add that to my comment.

Comment: I just found a mistake if yours as well. You are going from oldHeight to newHeight and oldWidth to newWidth. But we actually need that three times, for (oldHeight to newHeight) and (0 to oldHeight) and also the other way around. Its like having a 2x2 grid, 1x1 was initialised, your for-for takes 2x2, but we do not care about 1x2 and 2x1. I am just trying that the next minutes.

Comment: This `arr[i] = (bool *)realloc(arr, sizeof(bool) * new_width);` has to read `arr[i] = realloc(arr[i], sizeof(bool) * new_width);`. Not cast needed in C, BTW.